# Reduce image channels in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, rgb

I have an image with dimension of (128, 19, 3), i want to convert it to (128, 19, 1). I used this code (in python) but it converts the image size to (128, 19) not (128, 19, 1) which i want. thanks if anyone can help

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
images = glob.glob('D:\\thesis\\Paper 3\\Feature 
Extraction\\two_dimension_Feature_extraction\\stft_feature\\Training_set\\P300\\*.png')
img = Image.open(images[0]).convert('L')
```

Comment: If you have an actual NumPy array, e.g. from `array = np.array(img)`, have a look at [`expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html): `array = np.expand_dims(np.array(img), axis=2)`.

Comment: Thanks. it works. but dose not make sense for me

Comment: Your original image is a three-channel image, thus the array has shape `(128, 19, 3)`. When converting to mode `'L'`, you get a grayscale image, which is a single-channel image, thus its shape is `(128, 19)` - the additional, singleton dimension `(128, 19, 1)` is automatically flattened. If you explicitly want to have that dimension, you explicitly have to add it (back). One way to do that, is to use `expand_dims`, for further help on that function, see the linked documentation. If you have difficulties understanding NumPy arrays in general, start with a proper tutorial on that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your perfect reply and explanation

Answer (score 0):

simply add a dimension to the end of your array:

```
img = img[...,None]
```